# How to access the username of the logged user in Struts2?

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-security

I am using Spring Security and Struts2 in my web app project. I want to store the username value of the logged user in an `<s:hidden>` field. Is that possible? If not, whats the best alternative?

```
<sec:authentication property="name" />
<s:hidden name="value" value="%{name}" />
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the logged in username, in fact `UserDetails` object using :

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

This returns `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` object. You can get `username`, `authorities` from `UserDetails` object.